# PHP GET Request, sending headers

Tags: php

I need to perform a get request and send headers along with it. What can I use to do this?

The main header I need to set is the browser one. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you writing PHP code to perform the GET request, or do you want to use your browser (or something else) to simulate different user agents requesting your PHP pages?

Comment: I am writing code to perform the request and store the response as a string.

Comment: What "browser" header are you referring to? Do you mean you need to return the user agent string?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you're using cURL, you can use `curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'browser description')` to define the user-agent header of the request.

If you're using `file_get_contents`, check out this tweak of an example on the man page for [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .
              "User-agent: BROWSER-DESCRIPTION-HERE\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

Comment: Can I make a HTTPS request witht this?

Comment: @Purushotamrawat - Yes, if you follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744269/1571426), for quick/dirty test I added this to my `$opts`: `'ssl' => array('verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)` and it worked

Answer (score 13):

If you are requesting a page, use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

In order to set the headers (in this case, the `User-Agent` header in the HTTP request, you would use this syntax:

```
<?php
$curl_h = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');

curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        'User-Agent: NoBrowser v0.1 beta',
    )
);

# do not output, but store to variable
curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl_h);
```

Answer (score -5):

You can use the **[`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** function for that, example:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com?var=some_value');
```

**Note that:**

> Remember that header() must be called
>   before any actual output is sent,
>   either by normal HTML tags, blank
>   lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a
>   very common error to read code with
>   include(), or require(), functions, or
>   another file access function, and have
>   spaces or empty lines that are output
>   before header()  is called. The same
>   problem exists when using a single
>   PHP/HTML file.

Comment: I need to store the response from the request into a string for processing. So I cannot use this method.

Comment: @James Jeffery: I don't understand what you mean by that, could you be more specific or add more details to your question? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use AJAX? Or access PHP variables with Javascript?

Comment: The Header function is to modifiy the GET response not the actual request.

Comment: curl_setopt is the way to achieve this