# Using query inside php header

Tags: php, header

is the query recommended in PHP headers like this example below:
`header("location:index.php?id=1");` 
1-if not , what is the reason ?
2-what is the alternative method ?

Comment: There's no reason not to do that. You can use any valid URL. Have you experienced a specific problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032643/php-get-request-sending-headers
There is a misunderstanding about the third answer in this question , so I wanted to clarify to myself @ADyson

Comment: That question is a about _sending_ a request _from_ your code to some other URL. But `header("location:index.php?id=1")` is about redirecting the response to the current request away from the current script and onto a different URL. These are two different tasks. So...which one are you actually trying to achieve? I believe the answer you're referring to is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3032652/5947043), but it seems the answerer has misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to do that. You can use any valid URL.